# Mobile Safari Viewport - Preventing Horizontal Scrolling?

Tags: mobile, mobile-safari, viewport

I'm trying to configure a viewport for mobile Safari. Using the viewport meta tag, I am trying to ensure that there's no zooming, and that you can't scroll the view horizontally. This is the meta tag I'm using:

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content ="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

On my iPhone when I load the page, it seems to look okay:

[image: screenshot]

But I can scroll horizontally, so that it looks like this (this is as far to the right as I can go:

[image: screenshot]

When I swing it into landscape view, the page renders as expected, locking the horizontal scroll position.

I'm trying to figure out how to make this page not scroll horizontally at all. Is it possible that I've got some page element pushing the content out? I wouldn't even expect that to be possible with a correct viewport set, but I'm grasping at straws here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Is it possible that I've got some page element pushing the content out?

Yes, that is indeed the case. The viewport setting only defines the visible viewport area but does not deal with turning off sideway panning.

So, in order to avoid this from happening, set an overflow:hidden on the element that contains your content, or else, avoid elements from overflowing.

NB: other mobile browsers also support the viewport meta tag since a while, so you'll want to test in those as well.

Comment: Figures it'd be something that simple. Still not sure what was pushing it out, but using the overflow property on the main display element fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  FWIW, for me, it was a hard coded `______` for comments that caused it to be too wide.

Comment: what does NB stand for

Comment: NB is Latin for Nota bene which basically implies that what follows is an additional bit of good or useful information

Answer (score 15):

`body { overflow-x: hidden; }` also works.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work on Android devices. I have a page with `overflow-x` set to hidden and can still scroll with my mouse.

Comment: The question was for Mobile Safari :) For Android browsers, I've had success with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10739042/326073).

Comment: this also breaks vertical scrolling, making scrolling really slow

Comment: This works! I had no overflowing blocks or tags. I narrowed it down to just a `<label>` with a lot of text, but it was wrapping fine! Still it would scroll horizontal and reveal dead white space.

Answer (score 9):

Late to the party here, but I just had a similar problem where I had horizontal scrolling across an iPhone 5, the site was effectively showing as double the width, with the right hand half completely empty.

In fact, I just needed to change the viewport meta tag from:

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0' />
```

to:

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0' />
```

Adding the 'initial-scale' locked it down so that it only scrolled vertically as expected.

Answer (score 6):

This will prevent any elements pushing content out:

```
body div {overflow: hidden ;}  @ media queries
```

Comment: I used `body > div {overflow: hidden; }` to prevent unwanted cropping

Answer (score 4):

Try this variant:

```
html, body{
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```