# Viewport meta tag disables scrolling on iPad only for Chrome

Tags: html, ios, google-chrome, viewport, meta

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

Using the viewport meta tag along with a div height of 1024.469px on iPad 6th gen (980 x 1167 window size) means that anything greater than the height of the screen cannot be scrolled.

The scroll bar does show , however when trying to scroll it constantly bounces back the top and doesn't allow vertical scrolling.

Removing the viewport shows that the page fits on the iPad screen without needing to scroll.

Maybe this issue is caused because of the zoom?

I stripped down the entire page to find the culprit which is definitely this view port meta tag.

Increasing the height of the div by around 30 pixels allows the user to scroll even with the meta tag.

In fact, increasing the height to anything larger than 1024.469px seems to fix this issue.

I want to use the meta tag however also want my scrolling to work.

Answer (score 0):

So, in order to avoid this from happening, set an overflow:hidden on the element that contains your content, or else, avoid elements from overflowing.

NB: other mobile browsers also support the viewport meta tag since a while, so you'll want to test in those as well.

see in details. regard [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543495/mobile-safari-viewport-preventing-horizontal-scrolling#5588462)

Comment: Adding overflow hidden doesnt seem to make any difference.

Comment: I have found that this bug also affects sites like stackoverflow therefore this is something that isn't just an issue within my code.